# Error in if (!is.na(hroute$duration_base)) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, here-api, travel-time

I am currently attempting to measure travel time distance using the HERE API. The process was successful for the first 100,000 points; however, I encountered an error when processing the next set of points. The error message appears as follows:

```
No routes found.
Error in if (!is.na(hroute$duration_base)) { : argument is of length zero
```

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thank you

I've attempted to use another variable, but I'm still encountering the same problem.

Comment: This is often caused by typos or missing columns, reproduced with `if (!is.na(NULL)) 1 else 2`. If you are confident that your `hroute` is a frame or list and has a column/element named `duration_base`, then please [edit] your question and paste the output from `dput(head(hroute))` into a [code block]. (Heads up ... if that's a `data.frame` with more than one row, then you cannot use `if (!is.na(hroute$duration_base))` since `if` requires exactly length-1 in its condition. Please explain what you are hoping to accomplish.)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Eos Elinor! Please realize that a question's chance of success is highest in the first hour or so, quickly dropping after that. Especially when you are new, it can be advantageous to you if you "stick around" and try to reply to questions/requests quickly. It's too easy for people to lose interest and step away, never to return. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for more discussions on "reproducible questions", it can help your chances of getting faster and more-actionable answers. Good luck!